# Why do objects sent with send_data seem to be kept in memory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a Rails app (5.0.4, Ruby 2.3.3) that creates a PDF file with Prawn, and sends it to the user, using ActionController's send_data, like this:

```
 # data is a Prawn document    
 send_data data, type: 'application/pdf', disposition: 'inline', filename: 'document.pdf'
```

I've noticed on Heroku that the app seems to be using more and more memory with each document that is created and sent. I confirmed this on my local machine with some crude tests. Now, I placed `GC.start` after the `send_data` call and the problem seems to be resolved. Memory always goes back to a stable level.

My questions are, is `send_data` doing something to keep the object around for a long time? And isn't the garbage collector supposed to run "on its own" from time to time? Heroku shows a steady memory increase. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GC will run only when the system is under some memory pressure, specifically when the `heap_free_slots` are exhausted. You can see how many are available with `GC.stat`. Since you don't typically pay for used memory until you run out of it, there's little point in trying to free up space prematurely. Then the most space can be reclaimed in the fewest invocations of the garbage collector.

Comment: Thank you. When running without calling GC.start, I did notice the process free up a few MB's on its own, so I assumed that's the GC doing its thing automatically, however, it doesn't seem to free up as much memory as when I call it explicitly. I'm assuming then the "auto GC" runs in "light mode", as opposed to the manual trigger going after every single unused object. Any further clarification/confirmation on this is again much appreciated.

Comment: yes, on it's own it will run in "minor" mode. When you call it explicitly it runs in "major" mode, which will also GC objects in the second generation. Great article about it here: https://www.speedshop.co/2017/03/09/a-guide-to-gc-stat.html.